# Unstable Executor reconnecting again and again in spark standalone cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I am getting below stack trace and executor is lost and creating new executor connection.

```
INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(etlspark); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(sss); groups with modify permissions: Set()
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: TransportClient has not yet been set.**
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcOutboxMessage.onTimeout(Outbox.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$ask$1.applyOrElse(NettyRpcEnv.scala:232)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
```

What is reason of this stack trace ? Is it because of master and slaves machines java version is different or this related to cluster configuration. Please guide me because of which reason this error message comes?